# Android WebView doesn't fully zoom out

Tags: java, android, webview, zooming

In my Android app, I have a `WebView` and 6 buttons inside a `ConstraintLayout`. The `WebView` should zoom fully out on start, but it instead goes only to the width of the device.

The `WebView` is set up like `layout_width="fill_parent" layout_height="0dp"`, which should be `match_constraint`

My current code is:

```java
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

WebView XML:

```xml
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">
    </WebView>
```

I expect the `WebView` to show the full image/video, but it's still scrollable in horizontal direction, sometimes it even puts black bars below and above it.

Video demonstation: https://youtu.be/ucmLNksNGRI

Comment: And how webview html looks like?

Comment: There's no html, I set the webview url to the media file.

Comment: I think that it's a responsiveness problem from the web page. Did you try testing with another website ?

Comment: Anyway try seeing if [this](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) library helps.

Comment: I don't use any website. I load the file using: webView.loadUrl("file://" + files[index].getAbsolutePath());